# dispatchevent isn't working

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a strange problem:

I assigned the following variable:

```
public static const SERIES:String = "series";
```

Then in the same class I have the following function:

```
public function imgCompleteHandler(e:Event):void {
            var slidesXML:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
            for each (var serie:XML in slidesXML.slide){
                this.thumbs = serie.image;
                series.push(serie);
            }
                        trace("before");    
            dispatchEvent(new Event(SERIES));
                        trace("after");
        }
```

This is the class where the event is called:

```
package be.devine3.groep6.view.components.overview
{
    import be.devine3.groep6.model.AppModel;
    import be.devine3.groep6.view.components.series.Series;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class SerieOverview extends Sprite
    {
        private var loader:Loader;
        private var appModel:AppModel;
        public function SerieOverview()
        {
            this.appModel = AppModel.getInstance();

            appModel.addEventListener(AppModel.SERIES, seriesLoadedHandler);
        }
        public function seriesLoadedHandler(e:Event):void{
            for each (var slideModel:XML in appModel.series) {
                var serie:Series = new Series(slideModel);
                addChild(serie);
            }
            }


    }
}
```

Now for some reason the event does not get dispatched, the traces I placed before and after the dispatch event both get triggered. Anyone know why the dispatch event doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Its kind of hard finding the problem by tje code you posted. Easy check: make sure that you are adding the eventlistener BEFORE the event is dispatched. Add a trace in the method where you add the listener to be sure it is set before the dispatch.

Answer (score 0):

Is your AppModel getInstance() method also initializing the AppModel class? If so the event is likely being dispatched before you add the event listener.

I always use this flow:

1) Create Instance of class

2) Attach initialization event listeners

3) Call a public init() method ( i.e. AppModel.instance().init(); )